# VirtualizedLists should never be nested error

Tags: react-native

I'm building a mobile application with React Native, and I have a `ScrollView` inside one of the pages.

The problem is that I have in this page a `FlatList` so when I go to that page, I get this error:
`VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScroolViews with the same orientation...` The thing is, I set the `ScrollView` `nestedScrollEnabled` to `true` and I also set the `FlatList's scrollEnabled` to `false` because I don't really need the scroll there (I'm using it to render items from an enum) so I thought that should fix the error, but the error still persist.

It looks like this:

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
  <MyComponent />
</ScrollView>
```

And `MyComponent` has this FlatList:

```
<FlatList
    scrollEnabled={false}
    style={{padding: 8,marginBottom: 8,}}
    data={categories}
    numColumns={numOfColumns}
    keyExtractor={category => category}
    renderItem={item => renderItem(item.item)}
/>
```

Comment: is the FlatList the only component inside the ScrollView?

Comment: @unSensei No, there are other components, but it is the only List there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add the property `nestedScrollEnabled={true}` to both the parents and the children:

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
  <MyComponent />
</ScrollView>

<FlatList
    nestedScrollEnabled={true}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    style={{padding: 8,marginBottom: 8,}}
    data={categories}
    numColumns={numOfColumns}
    keyExtractor={category => category}
    renderItem={item => renderItem(item.item)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but got the same error. I also rerun the app (not only hot reload).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ListHeaderComponent** and **ListFooterComponent** of the FlatList to render the other parts inside the scrollView. Using a FlatList inside a scrollview limits the performance of the FlatList.

```
<FlatList
ListHeaderComponent={
  <> 
   <AboveFlatList />
  </>
 }
data={yourData}
renderItem={this.renderComponents}
...
...
ListFooterComponent={
  <> 
   <BelowFlatList />
  </>
 }
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the FlatList I have inside the scrollView does not even have to scroll, I just use it to render few items from an enum. plus, There is another component inside that scrollView below the FlatList.

Comment: Have you tried to directly map from the enum inside {} instead of the flatlist?